# TypeScript any type not providing specific argument

Tags: typescript

I have a function that access local/session storage. It's guarded by a condition where if the window is defined, it can call the function.

This function spreads a generic `args` argument. I've defined the type as `any[]` to simplify development.

Inside of the `useSessionStorage` function, I get this TypeScript error:

> An argument for 'key' was not provided.

How would I get around this?

```
export const useStorage = ( storage: any, key: string, initialValue: any, options = {} ) => {
  const { deleteKeyIfValueIs = null } = options as any
...
export const useSessionStorage = ( ...args: any[] ) => 
  useStorage( typeof window !== `undefined` && sessionStorage, ...args ) // <- Error here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `useStorage` requires 3 or 4 arguments, and the `args` of `useSessionStorage` would pass one or even than 4 arguments, so we cant' use `any[]` here. To be more type-safe, you can try following change

```
// change
(...args: any[])
// into
(...args: [string, any, object?])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wK6uAZRtAQwHNg4BeOACnUJIC44DkBPAGjgGthmH0oBLZEXaD+MfgQA2ANSkZgDJmzgQw4lKnJwA3gF8AlOQB8OgFBxEG+NoAmwScBjAA0twCSAM1mT5bzRWQMSUldLVV1NEZNJVNdU1BIWEs0TGwcYFRUfhQ8WlIKSgA6YoIoIlQGAG0+QWFGFnYIACMAK2AEGAB+AF1DMhNzOCxcfChiYEoYZjBgCA84AHdBGwgFuABCMgoAAwxkOw9BYBttuAAyM7hsTOzkXLGSdmLC0vL9IA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that args could have any length, so there is no guarantee for it to actually have a key value. To avoid this error you could mark the key argument (and everything that follows) as an optional parameter (or setting a default value) with the necessary handling. What you are not really handling though, is if the passed argument for key is not actually a string (since args is an any array).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose on of the follow solution

```
// tell typescript compile the args is a tuple
useStorage(typeof window !== `undefined` && sessionStorage, ...(args as [string, any, any])); 

// or use a Tail generic
type Tail<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = Parameters<F> extends [any, ...infer T] ? T : unknown;
useStorage(typeof window !== `undefined` && sessionStorage, ...(args as Tail<typeof useStorage>))
```